# How to get SignTool.exe and a few other tools in windows 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, code-signing

If you decide to sign your code, you'll need:

- signcode.exe
- makecert.exe
- cert2spc.exe
- pvk2pfx.exe

I wana download just this files without having to download the entire Windows SDK. Is this possible? And if it is, which one of these should i choose to download?

[image: Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4]

**Some of these options are disabled because i have .NET Framework 4.6 installed and the setup is detecting it as a Pre release version of .NET Framework 4 as shown in the picture.**

[image: Setup Install]

Comment: Usually should be Tools.

Comment: They are SDK tools, no way around that.  If you have Visual Studio installed then you already have them.  Simply run the commands from the Visual Studio Command Line shortcut.  If you don't have VS then you can't skip getting the SDK installed.  The one in your screenshot is a very old version so its .NET version detection is not necessarily reliable.  Get the most recent one.

Comment: I have VS 2015 installed but i can't find SignTool.exe anywhere. I think i will install VS 2015 again and tty than.